# visual composer front end text error

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend, visual-composer

I use a [WordPress website](https://www.brigadefitness.com) in the backend admin site. I use visual composer to edit the page, now I was facing some error on that plugin please help me to fix that bug.

See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKJsg.png) for that error.

Comment: I think you have entered data in text mode

Comment: No @SudharshanNair I was used visual composer plugin tool to edit that page.

Comment: Can you go through this link https://wpexplorer-themes.com/total/docs/visual-composer-issues/

Comment: Just check, if you are getting any error in error.log file